# Difference between meta charset="utf-8" and Notepad++ utf-8 encoding?

Tags: html, encoding, meta

Do I need to do both of them, only set the notepad++ encoding or only do it in the meta tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save as “UTF-8” (and not as “UTF-8 without BOM”) in Notepad++, then the `meta` tag is not needed, since browsers and search engines will infer the encoding from the BOM. This is what actually happens, and it is being defined formally in clause [8.2.2.1 Determining the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) in HTML5.

Writing a `meta` tag does not change the actual encoding. If present, it should match the encoding, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tags tells the browser what encoding the file has been saved in, so it needs to match the encoding you tell notepad++ to save it in. If you were to save it in UTF-8 which uses a variable number of bytes per character, and have a meta tag stating ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) then the browser will interpret each single byte as a character.

For example, if you save a cent character in a UTF-8 encoded document then it'll use two bytes: C2A2. However, if you interpret those bytes as Latin-1 you'll get two characters. Oddly enough, the second of those is the cent character.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag tells the web browser what encoding to open it as, not notepad. You need to set it in notepad to make sure that it is editing the files in UTF-8 format. So the answer is both.